# React Native firebase Android not return refreshToken when auth()

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

when I try signin with EmailLink(`signInWithEmailLink`) or EmailAndPassword(`signInWithEmailAndPassword`) then return `refreshToken` in iOS but Android is not. How to get `refreshToken` when signin in Android?

Environment:

```
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.5.0",
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^18.5.0",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.72.5",
```